# How to get HttpServletRequest in thread?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, rest

I am using spring with resteasy,I have created theradpool with size 10,and using Executor-service,to execute my long method simultaneously.I need to send `HttpServletRequest` object to each thread. but getting the below error

```
>     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.LoggableFailure: Unable to find contextual data
> of type: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
```

I need `HttpServletRequest` in thread because application DAO layer works on `HttpServletRequest`.

Here is the code , Please help me how to get the `HttpServletRequest` Object inside thread.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

final StringBuilder failedDocTransaction = new StringBuilder();

for (MyObject objectinstance : MyObjectList)
        {

            Future<String> result = executorService.submit(new Callable<String>()
            {

                @Override
                public String call() throws Exception
                {
                    try
                    {
                        MyMethod(objectinstance.getRowId(), objectinstance.getFileVersion(), request);
                    }
                    catch (NFARuntimeException exception)
                    {
                        failedDocTransaction.append(exception);
                    }
                    return failedDocTransaction.toString();
                }
            });
            resultList.add(result);
        }
```

Comment: When you spawn a thread the request finishes quickly and will be finished. There is no request available. However tying your DAO to the request is bad design in the first place, your web layer should be a small integration layer and transform things into objects/messages for lower layers. You shouldn't tie it to the web, but use wrapper and create that wrapper in your web layer. That frees the rest of the application to be tied to the web.

Comment: @M.Deinum :Thanks for your response, Is there any way we can send HttpServletRequest object into Threads?